# Issue with a combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I've made a new combobox property : readonly.
I'm changing the dropdownstyle to simple.
There is a small combobox where i only need to see first 2 char.
The issue is when i change the dropdownstyle to simple since the text is longer then the space it's always at the end

All my property is doing : When you click save it changes the dropdownstyle of the combobox and make it to simple. So it looks like a textbox.

what I see is the last 2 letters of the combobox item
"RE"

the second link : how it should be you guys should see the 11 up there. It's the first 2 letters of the combobox item

http://img685.imageshack.us/img685/1150/secondd.jpg

Ex : 11 codetest

i want to see "11"

i see "st"

I'm trying selectionStart doesnt seem to work.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Might want to put what language yo are working in.

Comment: Seconded. Not only to understand your question, but also to attract people who have that language in their favourite tags.

Comment: Done i've added vb.net on the flag thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. A screen shot might help illustrate your problem. Also, could you please explain what your first sentence about readonly has to do with anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does sound like a selection issue. Can you just load the first two characters? ie `"asdf".Substring(0,2)` = `"as"`

Comment: Issue is i will lose the rest when I want to enable it back.
Is there any other way without having to cut the text?

Comment: try setting the focus to another control on the form, this may reset the activetext selection

Comment: I've done another method, actually changeing the display member